Method of calculating dual as best possible lower bound when primal is a maximization
A method I learned that feels more intuitive to calculate the dual is as follows:
For a minimization problem in standard form:
\begin{align}
&\min &&f(x)  \\
&\text{s.t.} \\
& &&h(x) = 0  : \lambda \\
& &&g(x) \leq 0 : \mu
\end{align}
The dual can be found as
\begin{align}
\max_{\lambda \in R, \mu \geq 0} \quad \min_{x} \quad L(f(x)
\end{align}
where the Lagrangian $L = f(x)+\lambda h(x) +\mu g(x)$
where the minimization problem can be replaced by the KKTs (constraints in the $\max$ problem), and any parameters in the Lagrangian would persist in the $\max$ problem's objective function.
The minimization of the Lagrangian over the primal variables is the dual function (lower bound), and maximizing this over the dual variables provides the best possible lower bound.
For example, if we had as the primal:
\begin{align}
&\min &&c x \\
&\text{s.t.} \\
& &&a x - b = 0  : \lambda \\
& && -x \leq 0 : \mu
\end{align}
Then $L = c x + \lambda(a x - b) -\mu x$
The KKTs of the $\min$ are:
$\frac{\delta L}{\delta x} =  c + \lambda a - \mu = 0$
Then the dual would be
\begin{align}
&\max_{\lambda} && -\lambda b\\
&\text{s.t.} \\
& && c + \lambda a \geq 0
& && \end{align}
I'm confused as to who to apply this method to a primal that is a maximization. I can get the dual problem (a max) of the primal (as a min), but how do I translate back so that I have the corresponding dual problem (a min) of the original primal problem (a max)?
Say the primal is:
\begin{align}
&\max && c x \\
&\text{s.t.} \\
& &&a x - b = 0  : \lambda \\
& &&-x \leq 0 : \mu
\end{align}
Then the primal rewritten as a $\min$ is:
\begin{align}
&- \min && -c x \\
&\text{s.t.} \\
& && a x - b = 0  : \lambda \\
& && -x \leq 0 : \mu
\end{align}
where $L$ corresponding to the new negated objective function ($-c x$) is $L = -c x + \lambda(a x - b) - \mu x$
And the corresponding dual problem is:
\begin{align}
&\max_{\lambda} && - [-b \lambda] 
&\text{s.t.} \\
& && \lambda a \geq c
\end{align}
Is it correct that the dual problem is then the following? Or is there an error in applying the first (-) from the original $(-)\min(-f(x))$?
\begin{align}
&\max_{\lambda} && \lambda b 
&\text{s.t.} \\
& && \lambda a \geq c
\end{align}
At this point, if we wanted to get the dual problem as a $\min$, we have:
\begin{align}
&- \min_{\lambda} && -\lambda b 
&\text{s.t.} \\
& && \lambda a \geq c
\end{align}
But this seems like an odd ending point, since there is still a final negation on the outside of the minimization. What should I be doing instead?
Thanks for any insight, and sorry that my formatting is a little off (first time poster).

Welcome to OR.SE.  What type is your problem? (An LP or MILP or NLP). It seems you ask for linear problem. If you ask for an LP, please see this link.
